I don't know where to put my mp.mpf to have good precision
I want to have a good precision at the end of the road for the last print but the only result I receive is 0.0 while for the print(conv_dichotomy(6, 9, g, 10) it prints "(35, [6, 6.0000000000873115])". I think I have to use the mpmath library for this exercice but I don't know where to use it in the code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp

mp.mp.dps= 10

#...another part of the code

def g(x):
    return pow(x, 2) - 17


def cut(a,b,f):

    if f(a) < 0 :
        if f((b-a)/2) < 0:
            return [(a+b)/2,b]
        else : 
            return [a,(a+b)/2]
    else :
        if f((b-a)/2) > 0 :
            return [(a+b)/2,b]
        else :
            return [a,(a+b)/2]
    

#|f(n) - f(conv(k))| < 10^-k

def conv_dichotomy(a, b, g, k):
    lowerBound = a
    higherBound = b
    interval = []
    count = 0
    while higherBound - lowerBound > pow(10, -k):
        interval = cut(lowerBound, higherBound, g)
        lowerBound = interval[0]
        higherBound = interval[1]
        count += 1
    return count, interval


print(conv_dichotomy(6, 9, g, 10))   

def dichotomy(a,b,f,k):
    tmp, interval = conv_dicho(a, b, f, k)
    lowerBound = interval[0]
    higherBound = interval[1]
    result = (higherBound - lowerBound) / 2
    return result

print(dichotomy(8, 10, g, 20))

I tried to put my variables in mp.mpf at a lot of positions in my code so the final result can have a good precision. I tried putting a = mp.mpf(a)/ b= mp.mpf(b) in the cut function, the same in the other functions and to print with mp.nprint(..., 10) either one at the time or all at the same time and it did'nt work

What is conv_dicho?  Is pow the builtin one?  How about mp.power? Or x**2?  I don't know if that matters if  x is a int.

conv_dicho is conv_dichotomy srry for the typo, pow is indeed the bultiin one and I've tried mp.power or x**2 but it works the same
